# Prevent email change on password reset laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

How I can prevent email change on password reset page in Laravel?

I have input email:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="email" readonly type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ $email ?? old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
```

I pasted attribute `readonly`, but input email is empty. How I can pass email user and prevent change email for it?

In ResetPasswordController I have:

```
 public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    $email = //getUserEmail ?
    return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
        ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
    );
}

/**
 * Get the password reset validation rules.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function rules()
{
    return [
        'token' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|exists:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ];
}
```

How I can change `$request->email` on current user email, who reset password?

Comment: if you remove `readonly`. do you able to get value then ?

Comment: @H45H nope... .

Answer (score 0):

If i am getting your question well you want to show email but in readonly only format for reset password page. i am suggesting you some way for it. feel free to use any.

**Solution 1 :** inside, ResetPasswordController -> showResetForm()

```
    $password_resets = DB::table('password_resets')->get();
    foreach($password_resets as $password_reset)
    {
        if (Hash::check($token, $password_reset->token)) { // checking hash match with requested token
            // here if hash match with token
            $email = $password_reset->email;
        }
    }
```

Here, we are looping through password_resets table and checking if `reset password token` matches with actual `hashed token` in table. you can easily use `$email` inside `reset.blade.php`  like so :

`<input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ isset($email) ? $email : '' }}" required readonly>`

**Solution 2:**

At the time of sending password reset email you can pass email as `base64_encode` and can access it  using `base64_decode` at the time of reset password.

Hope, this helps you. enjoy coding :)